# How could I have each new cell framed?

Tags: hyphenation

I am looking for a way to have a frame around each new cell of any style in Mathematica. This is very helfpful for me because I have an optical guess where to put the hyphenation point( -) before the right cell margin. (there is no hyphenation rules for my language). Is this possible programmatically without the use of the Options Inspector? Could these frames have a specific colour or be dashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CellFrame -> True]
```

Or just for the notebook you're working on:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], CellFrame -> True]
```

To reset change `True` to `Inherited`.

Comment: @Buzing Thank you for your answer! Is it possible also to have a new  "style" for these frames too?

Comment: @kornaros yes. create a stylesheet and add the style. Plenty of examples on this site